# What is needed to set up a Pi as a local server?

Tags: wifi, server, wifi-direct

I can find plenty of articles about setting a Raspberry Pi up as a regular server. My goal is to set up a Pi as a local server.

A simplified scenario would be as follows: I have a Pi, no internet or cellular connection, and 5 smart phones. I want the phones to be able to connect to each other using the Pi as the middleman.

Is the Raspberry Pi the right choice for a project like this? (I have never used one before) Assuming it is, what will I need besides the obvious SD card, keyboard, mouse, display cables, and power supplies? After a bit of research it sounds like all I would need is a Wi-Fi adapter such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY)

Comment: Hello and welcome! I think you should be just a little bit more specific. After all a local server could be anything that provides some network or data service. Right from wikipedia: Typical computing servers are database server, file server, mail server, print server, web server, gaming server, and application server. So what is it you want? What kind of service do you expect the Pi to provide for those clients (the cell phones)?

Comment: At its most basic point, I am trying to build a gaming server.  I imagine the Pi analyzing input from the phones, storing certain information server side, and forwarding other information to the clients. A plus side would be so that the Pi can be uploaded with music and play this music through a headphone jack connected to the Pi during the game.  Note: the game is a custom one I have already created a phone version of

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you only want to be able to have a local server you could use a router that supports wifi(no internet needed) and attach your raspberry pi. You would need to do some configurations of course. Then when you turn your Wifi on the phones can connect to it.

With only the Pi and your Edimax adapter, basically, you would be setting up a wireless access point(without a connection to the internet). I do not know specifically what you are going to be doing but you might want to get an external hard drive for extra storage(its up to you). A great example of someone doing this is the [Pirate Box](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-PirateBox/)(one of many variations of the original idea at [piratebox.cc](http://piratebox.cc)). Some use more components than others. [Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-wireless-dead-drop-file-sharing/) is another variant. Hope that helps!

Comment: In your first sentence you say that a modem is required; this isn't true.  A modem would be required to connect to the internet, but a simple router is all that is required to create a local intranet.

Comment: Very cool! The second link you showed looks like what I envisioned.  Thank you!

Comment: @Jacobm001: You're right! I interchange those words loosely but they are totally different. Thanks for pointing that out!